# "That awkward moment when"

Tags: clauses

I know when people use the phrase "that awkward moment when", it is clearly a sentence fragment. What exactly is it called though? A dependent clause? A noun clause? I have no idea.

Comment: It’s not a clause at all—it’s just a noun phrase, modified by a relative clause.

Comment: It is, as you stated, a [*sentence fragment.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sentence+fragment) You could call it an *intentional fragment.*

Comment: I think it is just elliptical.  The ubiquitous 'meme' phrase really  intends '[We all know] that awkward moment when X happens'.  In that context it is not dependent, it is just the object of the sentence, the thing we all know.  As such it is a (free) relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the structure would be made up of the following:

That awkward moment + when...

Where 'when' is a relative pronoun, and "when..." is a relative clause. The first part is just a noun phrase.

The completed "that awkward moment when blah blah blah" is just a noun phrase modified by a relative clause.